# How to animate a directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

As you can see from this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P2Y9a1Apze6xzTIK6lKu?p=preview)
I have a simple project viewer.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-animate.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ProjectsController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <p>{{ name }}</p>

    <div class="slider">
    <div class="project" ng-repeat="project in projects">
                        <projects-info info="project"></projects-info>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'hello world';
    $scope.projects = [
    {
        link: '#',
        img: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}',
        description: 'Project 1'
      },
    {
      link: '#',
      img: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}',
      description: 'Project 2'
    },
    {
      link: '#',
      img: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}',
      description: 'Project 3'
    },
    {
      link: '#',
      img: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}',
      description: 'Project 4'
    },
    {
      link: '#',
      img: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}',
      description: 'Project 5'
    }];

  $scope.numOfProjects = 8;


}]);

app.directive('projectsInfo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'projectsInfo.html',
  };
});
```

My objective is to make the projects animate (more specifically, grow in size) when I hover over them. I've tried adding jquery to the html in a script tag but that didn't do anything. I've seen people use the 'link:' in their directive but I haven't seen a clear example where I can implement it to mine. My challenge is that I want to do this through angular, not css.

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to touch your js, do it in your css like this:

```
.project {
    transition:  0.2s;
}
.project:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);

}
```

Here's the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mSFuhbYtQyKKMaVzhY5I?p=preview)

---

Ok, because you really want to do it with angularjs **Which I don't really recommend just to execute for this requirement** and just for the sake of demonstration and 'educational' purposes you may do it like this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hw68ZepToj02kEjRATvT?p=preview)
using `ng-mouseover`, `ng-mouseleave` and `ng-class`

```
<div ng-mouseover='project.isHovered = true' ng-mouseleave='project.isHovered = false' ng-class='{hovered: project.isHovered}' class="project" ng-repeat="project in projects">
        <projects-info info="project"></projects-info>
</div>
```

then in your css:

```
.project {
    transition:  0.2s;
}
.project.isHovered {
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but for educational purposes I would like to do it through angular also

Comment: @user5812721 the proper way is using CSS animations. you should learn how to toggle classes on elements to achieve the desired animation instead

Comment: Oh okay, how do you toggle then with angularjs/ jquery?

Comment: @user5812721 I updated my answer to demonstrate what you wanted